# Aligning uncommon characters in java

Tags: java, unicode, character

I am doing a chess game in Java and I want to print the board, with the existing figures on it. The problem with that though, is that the 'space bar' character is shorter than the chess figure character. I was wondering if there is a way to align them to match. Or if I can get the width of a figure and print a space with the same width?

I have noticed that the 'space bar' character after a figure charcter appears to be smalled than the usual one. Having said that I couldn't manage to align them.

Note: I have problems aligning them with console font of 14+, with 12 or less, I can manage to align them just fine. The problem with it is that the chess figures are so small, some of them can't be distinguished to be white or black.

Edit:

```
System.out.print("   ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        System.out.print("   " + i + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        System.out.print("   ");
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            System.out.print("-------");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == null){
                System.out.print("|     ");
            } else { 
                System.out.print("|  " + board[i][j].getSymbol() + "   ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("| " + i);
    }
    System.out.print("   ");
    for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        System.out.print("-------");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("   ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        System.out.print("   " + i + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
```

this is the code I am currently using.

Comment: I still can't manage to align them, I edited the post with the code I am using, though I don't know if it would be usefull, because It won't work without the board initialized and filled with figures

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what is the difference between the no-break space and the regular space though?

Comment: It depends on the glyphs being used. It *shouldn't* make a difference, but I've seen it make one before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

If you display the output in the terminal or with an IDE, that should be monospace by default. If it's not, change it (see setting options).

If the the output is on an graphical application, try to change the font seeting.

Comment: It uses system.out.print(), so it's not on a graphical application

Comment: In that case search in your terminal or IDE settings. What do you use ?